# Редирект на другую страницу с передачей get запроса и открытием popup окна с информацией, в случае правильного значения get

Tags: javascript, jquery, get, popup

Пользователь после оплаты переходит на success.php где собраны все данные о проведенной операции, все проверяется, после чего делается редирект на другую страницу сайта с get запросом, например /?order=ok (если все совпадает) где открывается попап окно с информацией. Как передать параметр get чтобы окно открылось?

Comment: window.location.href="http://example.com?q=test"

Comment: как получить GET параметр есть много статей, например: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448545/how-to-retrieve-get-parameters-from-javascript